# Stuck inside twrp, can't get out

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, custom-roms, rom, huawei

Help!

Last question I asked was a software issue. Anyway I am stuck in twrp.

I just formatted my phone this time in twrp and it was successful. I then installed my stock/custom rom and it was successful again. Then when I rebooted it to system, it booted back into twrp. I formatted it again. But this one time after the first formatted it said install supersu, so I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try flashing a custom rom again? If not please do. The recovery mode might some how removed your system (my guess). Try flashing some other roms.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert an SD card in your device? If yes then take a screen shot about what is it about. Sorry but I forgot the button combination. Try power with volume up or down.

Comment: Power+Volume Down has always worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too. Just flash twrp from Fastboot.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it 2 weeks ago. I just locked the bootloader in fastboot and then fatboot oem unlock did not work. I was worried but never gave up, then I saw a new wat to unlock bootloader in fastboot. It was fastboot oem unlock-go